# How to update common content of several pages of a website at once

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, content-management-system

I want to update 12-15 pages of a website all at once. But currently I'm changing them manually. They have common navbar and news feed at the bottom. Any ideas?

Comment: Use a CMS, use PHP includes / requires? So many different options.

Comment: Use common header and footer and include this on every page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [PHP Includes!](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) They're super easy to use and super useful for this exact purpose! Take all of the header and move it to its own file, call it header.php for ease sake. Do the same with the footer, navbar, anything that you want to be consistent across pages.

Now go back into all of your pages (This part only needs to be done once), and at the top of your document, enter:

```
<?php
    include 'header.php';
    include 'footer.php';
    include 'sidebar.php';
    include 'whateverYouWant.php';
?>
```

Now everytime that you need to update those header and footer pages, you can do it from header.php and footer.php, and whenever the page is requested from a user, it will process the include function and grab the new updated header and footer.

When updating content on the page in the body, or even making a new page entirely, you just need those includes and you've got the "backbone" of that page done, the rest is content.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is a way. 
Let's use PHP for this example.
Make 2 separete files named header.php and footer.php
Fill in the data you want, for example, logo, navigation and social networks. 
Now on every page just use php include command:

```
<?php include 'PATH_TO_THE_FILE_YOU_WANT_TO_INCLUDE.php';?>
//Header and footer examples
<?php include 'header.php';?>
<?php include 'footer.php';?>
```